# Difference between かおり and におい

Tags: meaning, word-choice, usage, nuances

In a TV show I am watching (孤独のグルメ, perhaps many of you have heard of it) the gentleman is about to drink some coffee but pauses to savour the aroma.
He says

> いい かおり だ

Which I translate as "good aroma".
Am I right in saying that におい is simply "smell"?

So perhaps

> 台所から　においに来ています　　a smell is coming from the kitchen

and

> 台所から　かおりに来ています　　an aroma is coming from the kitchen

(this may not be correct Japanese, please correct me)

So in example #2 it is implied there is a nice smell like food is cooking ("aroma") but in example #1 something could be burning or rotting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, `におい` is just "a smell".  It is in fact neutral, but without `いい` in front of it, I usually perceive it as a bad one (as I also do with "smell" in English).  Like if you say, "What a smell!" in English, I think most people would take this to mean a bad smell rather than a good one.

Also, to say "smells" or "producing a smell", the form is　 におい・かおり　**が**　する.

> - 台所はにおいがしています。　→　A smell is coming from the kitchen.
> - 台所はかおりがしています。　→　An aroma/good smell is coming from the kitchen.

Note that you will often hear `いいかおり` even though it's kind of redundant.

Comment: 台所はにおいがする sounds better to me. I seem to remember having read somewhere about how these sensory verb phrases tend to be stative, but can't remember where.

Comment: Ah, here we go: http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%8A%B6%E6%85%8B%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E. I guess it's similar to English, "The kitchen smells", not "The kitchen is smelling".

Comment: @dainichi:  But isn't it similar to saying something like `青い目をしている子` (The girl with ["that has"] blue eyes)?

Comment: This dictionary treats them differently
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/120514/m0u/%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/ (1㋐ and 2㋓). They're definitely different with regards to stative-ness.