# Does this sentence make sense "タバコとっても大嫌いよ、タバコの香り特にな"

Tags: grammar

Im writing an essay about myself in Japanese to practice my grammar and such. And I want to know if this sentence sounds natural or not and whether Iam using "特に" "香り" and "な" correctly. And if it does sound unnatural what are some other ways I can better phrase it to sound less forced.

Comment: Not quite.  Hint:  [Difference between かおり and におい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15684/78)

Comment: Nonspecific proofreading request is off-topic here. Can you specify which part of this sentence you are uncertain about?

Comment: Is it common to write essays in such a highly colloquial language in your own culture?  It definitely is not in the Japanese-speaking world.